# Why does the Firefox mobile address bar disappearing on scroll seem to have an effect on a div with 100% height?

Tags: android, css, firefox, firefox-android

I have a simple website available [here](https://jackiergleason.com). This website has some weird behavoir on firefox mobile (works fine on firefox for osx). It seems that it is including the address bar in the height so I get a white box like this while scrolling to the point the address bar disappears...

[image]

As you can see the white box matches the distance I have scrolled in the address bar. Once I scroll back up the address bar shows up and the gap goes away. I have been careful to make sure all of my heights are right and I don't seem to have the same issue in mobile chrome (although the address bar also doesn't disappear in chrome).

Why is this happening and how do I handle it?

Comment: This could be a bug. Have you considered filing an issue [in the repo](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues)?

Comment: I have not, I just assumed it was more of a "feature" :-)

Comment: FTR this is using pixel 3 stock rom with newest version of FF